# printf on console vs sh script

Tags: bash, unix, printf, solaris

I am using a printf command to add some bytes on my file so that it acts like a Byte-Order-Mark.

the following is my SH script

title: add_bom.sh

```
FILE=$1
printf '\xFF\xFE' >> $1
```

On my PuTTY terminal, when I do directly

```
printf '\xFF\xFE' >> test.xls
```

the result is correct as expected and xxd test.xls displays ff and fe at the first line

However, when I run it via SH

```
sh  add_bom.sh test.xls
```

the result is wrong and \xFF\xFE appears at the end of test.xls file as a text

Why it this so?

Comment: The `>>` redirection ***appends*** to the file, i.e. it adds the output *last* in the file.

Comment: Also, adding a BOM to a *binary* file like `.xls` is probably only going to make the file unreadable by Excel.

Comment: Your tag indicates this is on Solaris; is that correct, and if so what version? Also, what is `sh` actually running? (Try `which sh` and `type sh` to find out.)

Answer (score 3):

The `>>` redirection operator always appends to the end of the file.

If you want to prepend, try something like

```
printf '\xff\xfe' >temp
cat otherfile >>temp
mv temp otherfile
```

However, adding an UTF-16 BOM to a file which is not a UTF-16 text file in the first place is almost certainly an error.